# set as start page in vs2012

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

back on vs2010 I had the option to choose a web project

set it as start project

and in it, set a specific aspx page as start page

so when I click `wrun` this page opens in my default browser

How can I set `start page` in vs2012?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project Properties > Web > **Specific Page**

[image]

[Property Pages Settings for Web Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164701.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

That has nothing to do with VS2010 or VS2012. Your problem is related to the fact that you use ASP.NET MVC. You don't have a start page because you don't have pages any more.

You could set a link in your browser to your actual start page or as Maxim suggests, you add the link to the project properties (specific page).

Comment: what was so wrong with my answer that you are so negative about it? It is still possible to set the start page in VS2012 when you use webforms (.aspx) as you did with VS2010. But it wasn't possible to set a start page in VS2010 when using ASP.NET MVC. Nothing has changed ...