# Set Startup Project in VS 2012 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Is there an easy way to set the web application as the startup project and not have it change automatically? In the solution explorer I right click on the project and hit "Set as Startup Project" but if I end debugging and try to start again, VS tries to set whatever page I'm working on as the startup project. Am I missing something or am I just being picky?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set web project as startup:**

Right click the solution, under common properties > startup project, ensure the correct startup project is selected:

**To set a specific page within the project:**

Right click on the project, select 'Web' then under 'Start Action' you can set exactly what page you would like to start. If you want to load a specific page, select the 'Start URL' option and enter a URL.  For example in MVC use `/Controller/Action`

[set as start page in vs2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580020/set-as-start-page-in-vs2012)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click the Project
2. Select **Properties**
3. Click on **Web**
4. Select **Specified Page**
5. Specifies the controller/action you want to always start. *Example: **Home/Index***
6. Enjoy!